# Weblogic Error Comments may not contain '--'

Tags: deployment, xml-parsing, weblogic12c

I am new to Weblogic. I have tried deploying the application and I got this error (with stacktrace). Has anyone come across this issue?

I have also created fresh domain to rule out the possibility of the domain being screwed up, but in vain.

```
<Oct 12, 2015 5:39:50 PM IST> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101064> <[WebAppModule(myApp-ear:/)] Error parsing descriptor in Web appplication "C:\Projects\myApp1\test\com.myOrg.myApp.app\trunk\myApp-ear\target\myApp-ear-1.10-SNAPSHOT\myApp-war-SNAPSHOT.war"
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Error at line:223 col:10 Comments may not contain '--'
    at weblogic.xml.stax.XMLStreamReaderBase.advance(XMLStreamReaderBase.java:206)
    at weblogic.xml.stax.XMLStreamReaderBase.next(XMLStreamReaderBase.java:237)
    at javax.xml.stream.util.StreamReaderDelegate.next(StreamReaderDelegate.java:60)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.DebugStreamReaderDelegate.next(DebugStreamReaderDelegate.java:89)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.BasicMunger2.next(BasicMunger2.java:425)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: Error at line:223 col:10 Comments may not contain '--'
    at weblogic.xml.babel.scanner.Comment.bufferData(Comment.java:60)
    at weblogic.xml.babel.scanner.Comment.read(Comment.java:79)
    at weblogic.xml.babel.scanner.Scanner.startState(Scanner.java:264)
    at weblogic.xml.babel.scanner.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:178)
    at weblogic.xml.babel.baseparser.BaseParser.accept(BaseParser.java:533)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
<Oct 12, 2015 5:39:50 PM IST> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149205> <Failed to initialize the application "myApp-ear" due to error weblogic.application.ModuleException: [HTTP:101064][WebAppModule(myApp-ear:/)] Error parsing descriptor in Web appplication "C:\Projects\myApp1\test\com.myOrg.myApp.app\trunk\myApp-ear\target\myApp-ear-1.10-SNAPSHOT\myApp-war-SNAPSHOT.war"
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Error at line:223 col:10 Comments may not contain '--'
    at weblogic.xml.stax.XMLStreamReaderBase.advance(XMLStreamReaderBase.java:206)
    at weblogic.xml.stax.XMLStreamReaderBase.next(XMLStreamReaderBase.java:237)
    at javax.xml.stream.util.StreamReaderDelegate.next(StreamReaderDelegate.java:60)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.DebugStreamReaderDelegate.next(DebugStreamReaderDelegate.java:89)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.BasicMunger2.next(BasicMunger2.java:425)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.VersionMunger._next(VersionMunger.java:342)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.VersionMunger.next(VersionMunger.java:230)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.VersionMunger.consumeInputStream(VersionMunger.java:595)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.VersionMunger.init(VersionMunger.java:485)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.VersionMunger.<init>(VersionMunger.java:86)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.VersionMunger.<init>(VersionMunger.java:62)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.VersionMunger.<init>(VersionMunger.java:50)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppReader2.<init>(WebAppReader2.java:47)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppDescriptor$MyWebAppDescriptor.createXMLStreamReader(WebAppDescriptor.java:274)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.AbstractDescriptorLoader2.createDescriptorBean(AbstractDescriptorLoader2.java:401)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.AbstractDescriptorLoader2.loadDescriptorBeanWithoutPlan(AbstractDescriptorLoader2.java:774)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.AbstractDescriptorLoader2.loadDescriptorBean(AbstractDescriptorLoader2.java:783)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppDescriptor.getWebAppBean(WebAppDescriptor.java:141)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.loadDescriptor(WebAppModule.java:1482)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.init(WebAppModule.java:253)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.init(WebAppModule.java:636)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.init(ScopedModuleDriver.java:162)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.init(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:74)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.init(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:84)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.InitModulesFlow.initModule(InitModulesFlow.java:312)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.InitModulesFlow.initModules(InitModulesFlow.java:325)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.InitModulesFlow.prepare(InitModulesFlow.java:378)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:706)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:35)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:237)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.prepare(EarDeployment.java:61)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:158)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:60)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppDeployment.prepare(AppDeployment.java:155)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doPrepare(DeploymentAdapter.java:39)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.prepare(DeploymentAdapter.java:191)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$1.transitionApp(AppTransition.java:21)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionApps(ConfiguredDeployments.java:240)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.prepare(ConfiguredDeployments.java:165)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(ConfiguredDeployments.java:122)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(DeploymentServerService.java:186)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(DeploymentServerService.java:94)
    at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused by: Error at line:223 col:10 Comments may not contain '--'
    at weblogic.xml.babel.scanner.Comment.bufferData(Comment.java:60)
    at weblogic.xml.babel.scanner.Comment.read(Comment.java:79)
    at weblogic.xml.babel.scanner.Scanner.startState(Scanner.java:264)
    at weblogic.xml.babel.scanner.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:178)
    at weblogic.xml.babel.baseparser.BaseParser.accept(BaseParser.java:533)
    at weblogic.xml.babel.baseparser.StartElement.parse(StartElement.java:77)
    at weblogic.xml.babel.baseparser.BaseParser.parseElement(BaseParser.java:453)
    at weblogic.xml.babel.baseparser.BaseParser.parseSome(BaseParser.java:326)
    at weblogic.xml.stax.XMLStreamReaderBase.advance(XMLStreamReaderBase.java:195)
    ... 44 more

Error at line:223 col:10 Comments may not contain '--'
weblogic.application.ModuleException: [HTTP:101064][WebAppModule(myApp-ear:/)] Error parsing descriptor in Web appplication "C:\Projects\myApp1\test\com.myOrg.myApp.app\trunk\myApp-ear\target\myApp-ear-1.10-SNAPSHOT\myApp-war-SNAPSHOT.war"
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Error at line:223 col:10 Comments may not contain '--'
    at weblogic.xml.stax.XMLStreamReaderBase.advance(XMLStreamReaderBase.java:206)
    at weblogic.xml.stax.XMLStreamReaderBase.next(XMLStreamReaderBase.java:237)
    at javax.xml.stream.util.StreamReaderDelegate.next(StreamReaderDelegate.java:60)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.DebugStreamReaderDelegate.next(DebugStreamReaderDelegate.java:89)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.BasicMunger2.next(BasicMunger2.java:425)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.VersionMunger._next(VersionMunger.java:342)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.VersionMunger.next(VersionMunger.java:230)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.VersionMunger.consumeInputStream(VersionMunger.java:595)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.VersionMunger.init(VersionMunger.java:485)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.VersionMunger.<init>(VersionMunger.java:86)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.VersionMunger.<init>(VersionMunger.java:62)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.VersionMunger.<init>(VersionMunger.java:50)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppReader2.<init>(WebAppReader2.java:47)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppDescriptor$MyWebAppDescriptor.createXMLStreamReader(WebAppDescriptor.java:274)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.AbstractDescriptorLoader2.createDescriptorBean(AbstractDescriptorLoader2.java:401)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.AbstractDescriptorLoader2.loadDescriptorBeanWithoutPlan(AbstractDescriptorLoader2.java:774)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.AbstractDescriptorLoader2.loadDescriptorBean(AbstractDescriptorLoader2.java:783)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppDescriptor.getWebAppBean(WebAppDescriptor.java:141)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.loadDescriptor(WebAppModule.java:1482)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.init(WebAppModule.java:253)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.init(WebAppModule.java:636)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.init(ScopedModuleDriver.java:162)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.init(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:74)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.init(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:84)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.InitModulesFlow.initModule(InitModulesFlow.java:312)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.InitModulesFlow.initModules(InitModulesFlow.java:325)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.InitModulesFlow.prepare(InitModulesFlow.java:378)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:706)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:35)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:237)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.prepare(EarDeployment.java:61)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:158)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:60)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppDeployment.prepare(AppDeployment.java:155)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doPrepare(DeploymentAdapter.java:39)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.prepare(DeploymentAdapter.java:191)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$1.transitionApp(AppTransition.java:21)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionApps(ConfiguredDeployments.java:240)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.prepare(ConfiguredDeployments.java:165)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(ConfiguredDeployments.java:122)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(DeploymentServerService.java:186)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(DeploymentServerService.java:94)
    at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused by: Error at line:223 col:10 Comments may not contain '--'
    at weblogic.xml.babel.scanner.Comment.bufferData(Comment.java:60)
    at weblogic.xml.babel.scanner.Comment.read(Comment.java:79)
    at weblogic.xml.babel.scanner.Scanner.startState(Scanner.java:264)
    at weblogic.xml.babel.scanner.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:178)
    at weblogic.xml.babel.baseparser.BaseParser.accept(BaseParser.java:533)
    at weblogic.xml.babel.baseparser.StartElement.parse(StartElement.java:77)
    at weblogic.xml.babel.baseparser.BaseParser.parseElement(BaseParser.java:453)
    at weblogic.xml.babel.baseparser.BaseParser.parseSome(BaseParser.java:326)
    at weblogic.xml.stax.XMLStreamReaderBase.advance(XMLStreamReaderBase.java:195)
    ... 44 more

Error at line:223 col:10 Comments may not contain '--'
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.createModuleException(WebAppModule.java:1848)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.loadDescriptor(WebAppModule.java:1516)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.init(WebAppModule.java:253)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.init(WebAppModule.java:636)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.init(ScopedModuleDriver.java:162)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: Error at line:223 col:10 Comments may not contain '--'
    at weblogic.xml.babel.scanner.Comment.bufferData(Comment.java:60)
    at weblogic.xml.babel.scanner.Comment.read(Comment.java:79)
    at weblogic.xml.babel.scanner.Scanner.startState(Scanner.java:264)
    at weblogic.xml.babel.scanner.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:178)
    at weblogic.xml.babel.baseparser.BaseParser.accept(BaseParser.java:533)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

Comment: Hi, it would be helpful to see some code with the Exceptions…

Comment: this is happening while deploying the ear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weblogic server failed to parse some of the comments used "" in struts-config.xml. Removing comments resolved the issue.But interestingly only few specific comments were causing the issue.